# Swap columns of an ndarray

Tags: python, numpy, multidimensional-array

I am trying to swap two columns from a 2d array such that

```
a = array([[1, 2, 3],
           [4, 5, 6],
           [7, 8, 9]])
```

becomes:

```
b = array([[1, 3, 2],
           [4, 6, 5],
           [7, 9, 8]])
```

How can I do that?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This would do it:

```
b = a[:, [0, 2, 1]]
```

It works by providing a `list` of column indices in the second-dimension position.  As always in Python, the indices are zero-based, so the first (leftmost) column is 0 and the third (rightmost, last) column is 2.

Comment: thanks for your fast reply, but it gives me IndexError: too many indices. (I have six columns so I did b = a[:,[1,3,4,5,6,2]]

Comment: You should use `[0,2,3,4,5,1]`